# Top 1 Profitable movie for each decade

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I need help with SQL Server query. I need to extract only the top 1 profitable movie for each decade.

Suppose there are 20 distinct decades and I only want to extract the top 1 profitable movie for each decade. Can someone help me with the query?

I have attached the screen shot for the reference. My result shows all the profitable movies for each decade. I only want the top 1 profitable movie for each decade.

For reference [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZBNL.png)

```
Select 
    decade, Movie_Title, Profit 
from 
    DW.IMDB_MOVIE
group by 
    decade, Movie_Title, profit
order by 
    decade, profit desc
```

Comment: This type of question has been answered many times on Stack Overflow. See the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag for answers.

Comment: You should be clear which database you're using. You tagged both mysql and sql-server, but these are different products and the answer to your task may be different depending on which of these database products you are really using. If you query `SELECT @@version;` you will find out what you are using.

Comment: Thanks, @BillKarwin for the reply. I am using  SQL Server database.

Answer (score 3):

One option is using `WITH TIES` in concert with the window function `row_number()`

**Example**

```
 Select top 1 with ties *
  From  DW.IMDB_MOVIE 
  Order by row_number() over (partition by decade order by profit desc)
```

**Or a nudge more performant**

```
with cte as (
Select *
      ,RN = row_number() over (partition by decade order by profit desc)
From  DW.IMDB_MOVIE 
)
Select * 
 From  cte 
 Where RN=1
```